# How can I refactor this function to support a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This function takes in a URL and a function. 
It gets a JSON object from the URL which is only 1 out of N pages. 
It then repeats the URL to get new JSON objects for each page. 
Then, it applies the supplied function to each of the received JSON objects.

LookUp is just a prebuilt object of options

```
export const getAndHandleData = (url, applyToEach) => {
  const firstLookup = new LookUp(url);
  request(firstLookup, (error, res, body) => {
    const numPagesToGet = parseInt(body.total, 10) / parseInt(body.pageSize, 10);
    for (let i = 1; i < numPagesToGet; i++) {
      const nextLookup = new LookUp(`${url}?page=${i + 1}`);
      request(nextLookup, applyToEach);
    }
    applyToEach(error, res, body);
  });
};
```

I want to be able to add a callback function parameter which is called after all N pages have finished applying the given function. I could do this with 'async' foreach / series, but I would prefer to avoid adding additional dependencies if possible.

Any ideas? Are Promises native in nodejs? I have never used them.

**EDIT**

I've realized that generators are available, so I'll simply call the callback after the generator has been called N times.

Comment: There's a specific site for code review questions: [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [Promises are supported natively in Node 4.x.x and above.](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/)